# Internal server error when using ejs with expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to nodejs and I'm trying to use ejs to template my website. But when I tried to set the view engine, I keep getting the error code 500 - Internal Server Error. Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var engines = require('consolidate');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var main = require('./routes/main');
var suoimo = require('./routes/suoimo');
var vungtau = require('./routes/vungtau');
var video = require('./routes/video');
var dalat = require('./routes/dalat');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));

app.use(express.static('./public'));

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use('/', index);
app.use('/video', video);
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/suoimo', suoimo);
app.use('/vungtau', vungtau);
app.use('/main', main);
app.use('/dalat', dalat);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

But if I set the view and view engine like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Everything work fine, anyone know why? Please help

Comment: because your html files are in folder "views " and not in "public" folder. 
And you should specifiy the view engine to express to know what to render

Comment: Following points may be that solve your issues.
- maybe you file extension is .html if you are using ejs then change extension to filename.ejs
- install ejs module again
- maybe you didnot return correct file name 
  return res.render('filename');   not use .ejs etc

Comment: @Shadow It worked, may u post an answer? I will approve. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I **tested your code** and everything **works fine**. But if I **uninstall** ejs I get error 500 Internal server error. I think that this is your problem. **Try to run** `npm install ejs` and try again with the same configuration, it should work fine now.